# SQL Server User Defined Function

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am trying to create a UDF which returns a SELECT statement.

The function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION closestCity
     (@givenLat decimal(11, 7),
      @givenLong decimal(11, 7),
      @locLat decimal(11, 7),
      @locLong decimal(11, 7)
     )
RETURNS nvarchar(100)123
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @city_name nvarchar(100)

    SELECT top 1 @city_name = name
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             SQRT(POWER(69.1 * (@locLat - @givenLat), 2) +
                  POWER(69.1 * (@givenLong - @locLong) * COS(@locLat / 57.3), 2)) AS distance, 
             name 
         FROM city) d
    WHERE d.distance < 35
    ORDER BY d.distance

    RETURN @city_name
END;
```

However it does not return my expected result. When I run the query 'manually' with the same values it does return the expected result however.

I figured out that running the query without the `ORDER BY` has the same result as it has running the UDF as I posted it. So is the `ORDER BY` somehow being ignored or am I just looking over something?

I would call the function like so;

```
SELECT name 
FROM city 
WHERE dbo.closestCity([lat], [long], city.latitude, city.longitude) = city.name;
```

But as I said this returns something different than running;

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    name
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         SQRT(POWER(69.1 * (@locLat - @givenLat), 2) +
              POWER(69.1 * (@givenLong - @locLong) * COS(@locLat / 57.3), 2)) AS distance, 
         name 
     FROM city) d
WHERE 
    d.distance < 35
ORDER BY 
    d.distance
```

Where `@givenLat` and `@givenLong` are coordinates send as decimals and `@locLat` and `@locLong` are the coordinates stored in the database.

Comment: Are you getting a null result back, or just a different city name than you expected?

Comment: your query confuses me, you calculate a distance which is nowhere related to anything in your table `city` and than you sort by that value which is the same for all rows and expect what?

Comment: @AnnL. I get a different city name.

Comment: @Aツ I calculate the distance from given latitude and longitude, and my city table also has latitude and longitude coordinates for each city and I then sort by the calculated distance from a city from the given coordinates so that the closest city would be first, which is the case if I 'manually' execute the query as I've stated above. But executing the UDF returns a different city than expected.

Comment: maybe you want to do that but thats not the query you've written. your distance column is completely unrelated to the table.

Comment: @Aツ Running the query manually does actually return the city which is the closest to the given lat and long, but the UDF isn't. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Luck.  Since the value you calculate for distance is going to be constant (since it's based solely on the parameters you sent in), sorting by it isn't going to have any effect.  So, which city you get back isn't random, exactly, it's not going to be predictable.  Another day, you might not get the city that is closest to the given lat and long.  If you used a different city for your manual test, you might not get the right city back.

Comment: @AnnL. Everything I try manually returns the expected result, with different coordinates it always returns the expected city name. Note that @ locLat and @ locLong are actually the columns city.latitude and city.longitude, so how will it be 'constant'?

Comment: within your function its constant

Comment: @Aツ Could you elaborate? I'm kind of new to SQL server. Would I just have to change @ locLat and @ locLong to their column names rather than adding them as a parameter to the UDF?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that within each run of the function, the calculated distance will be constant.  Let's say it's `25.00`.  You're querying `City` in the function, but you're not connecting that value to the records in `City` in any way. So when you say to sort by that value, it has no effect: for every record returned by your query, you get `25.00` as the value for distance.

Comment: I've attached an answer that rewrites the query.  I did it from memory, so no guarantees, but give it a try.  If it doesn't work, we can refine it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:  this is from memory.  It hasn't been tested.

```
CREATE FUNCTION closestCity
 (@givenLat decimal(11, 7),
  @givenLong decimal(11, 7),
 )
RETURNS nvarchar(100)123
AS BEGIN
  DECLARE @city_name nvarchar(100)

SELECT top 1 @city_name = name
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         SQRT(POWER(69.1 * (city.latitude - @givenLat), 2) +
              POWER(69.1 * (@givenLong - city.longitude) * COS(city.latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance, 
         name 
     FROM city) d
WHERE d.distance < 35
ORDER BY d.distance

RETURN @city_name
END;
```

You'd call it like this:

```
 select name
 FROM city 
 WHERE dbo.closestCity(city.latitude, city.longitude) = city.name;
```

... although, actually, if all you want is the city name that's closest for each city, you could do this:

```
SELECT  NearestCity = dbo.closestCity(city.latitude, city.longitude)
    ,   GivenCity = city.name 
FROM city
```

Or, if you want just a single city name and have the lat and long for that city already, you could call it like this:

```
SELECT  dbo.closestCity(@givenLat, @givenLong)
```

Comment: Thanks. This script was originally for MySQL which required you to give the columns as parameters. Doing it like this worked!

Comment: @MeesKluivers Glad it helped!